# Create View below dynamic View

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a label without defined height, her height will be set accordingly to the text that she receives from the array(can be any height).

Now I want to create a webview that goes below the label, if I create it through interface builder the webview will not receive clicks so I thought that i could create programmatically but how can I find the Y(CGRectMake(x,y,w,h)) after the label gets his height to create the frame for that position?

EDIT 1: What i want is to create a View below that label, but what happens is that when the view goes down because of the label she stops to receive clicks

EDIT 2: I Have a label below that is separator(Gray Line to separate) and then a View that programmatically will receive a WebView, but when the Label is short, the UIWebView is clickable, when I have a long label I can't click in the WebView.

The label can have like 50 or 500 as height soo tell me how can I Create a view below that label that will work properly

Thanks in advance

Comment: pls provide more details. why the webview doesnt receive clicks?

Comment: @Mr.T I've edited, I can't post images yes so I tried to explain has I could

Comment: what is the frame of label and webview ?

Comment: I've added the frame in the interface builder, Its a label then UIView(separator) and then a View that will receive the WebView

tell me if you don't understand or if I didn't answered your question

Comment: i meant the size. what is the size of label and size of the webiew ?

Comment: http://imgur.com/sjPztuN

This is my interface builder, the size is 328 width and 23 height in label and for the webview will be 328 width and 140 height

Comment: you cannot touch the webview exactly at the position where there is a label, you can touch below the label

Comment: I think I've made the constraints so the view would be always below the label, and the view goes there and loads the web view content but I cannot interact with it

Answer (score 0):

You can use auto layout here..

```
UILabel  *yourlabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    yourlabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    yourlabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    yourlabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    [self.view addSubview:infoLabel];

    yourlabel -- set leading , trailing and top constrain 
    below your label you can add your other view.
```

Comment: did you set LayoutConstraint on your label ?

Comment: yes i do, left, right, top and bottom space because the label is in the middle of 2 views

Answer (score 0):

To add webVIew under `UILabel`, you need to use `insertSubView` instead of `addSubView`.
Try looking into `insertSubview:atIndex:`

Also look into `insertSubview:aboveSubview`